# @Autowired doesn't work for JpaRepository in standard App

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to run code based on **[this](https://www.yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=www.yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1561.xyr6cdjEc4aUjOAVHDEJn4OLr1r84fMRUHJV-pcA7L0S1bcvDc5JA6j_bvOYgIa8.b236b6e0c63a7d78b038a86519374ac2db4c314e&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9dFa2ePbDzX7fH_cbK-eu2V8J4cbFpzDXVHZJKQvpytSGERVfWXp7WbRYB6GMIn7Tw,,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFGFO6Jjeal6buIw3XNPPByIW2o0i8Bvy5x6_1sPd_lJFAoEf4zBvL3AHU9QJ5hRIEgn_z26ZqCzNq6pmfXuJHisfT305k_iyo0uTWAEJPxqbSZNkKmy41SH3IFCD_O4FRA1AQw-WHx7CGo8EfpsSa_sDmc0a4GYbRbcPtModdAyiWyNRYjBrP5vKR65FxcVf4eHDy5250J6rSpwb6SaX0eTjLSPITLId7WxOOhx0MusG&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbWR6eDgwajdlVU9vQWlJeXlJNXBnNW0wWXJScGFtQWRQdGZBdC02UHFHQWhuSXNib0l0RjQ4ZFktTWZqNkhzTlpoRlVQVEtRdGVKQTlfY05OcXgxUUYzay1jbld6akFEd2QyMENtN05tOUUwRm0zVHloaklESSw,&sign=0f250521fad1733fc9dd6fc978bf16a4&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjlSKyJlbRuxUiMagqD7IEChNIhECNn1bzr2qM9KeM0leTNrt1933r2Zcxs6W4moTKoxHb-43HQMYtPW7miK0F6d&l10n=ru&cts=1506890082115&mc=2.9477027792200903&bu=uniq1506887844681179846)** and **[this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/)** **tutorials** the error occurred:

```
Field userRepository in hello.MainController required a bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' that could not be found.
```

Application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
    @RestController
    public class MainController {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public HttpEntity<Greeting> greeting(
                @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {

            Greeting greeting = new Greeting("...");
            greeting.add(linkTo(methodOn(MainController.class).greeting(name)).withSelfRel());

            return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```

Repository code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findAny();
}
```

There are no other error occurred. I can't understand the reason.

*Before, in another project*, simple code provided strange error: 
`call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@32eff876: startup date [Sun Oct 01 23:41:33 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) annotation on your interface.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findAny();
}
```

Another option is package scanning [`@EnableJpaRepositories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=UserRepository.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've already added it... I should go to sleep and not to sit at the computer..

Comment: You don't need an @Repository annotation when you are inheriting from JpaRepository (any other of the premade interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing "boot" keyword in one of dependencies in pom.xml.